# Mypy throws "has incompatible type " error when passing an argument with a subclassed type

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I created a generic type using python's `typing` module

```
TDbBase = TypeVar('TDbBase', bound=MyBaseClass)
```

I also defined two classes which subclass `MyBaseClass`

```
class MyFirstClass(MyBaseClass):
class MySecondClass(MyBaseClass):
```

I have a method that needs to take either an object of `MyFirstClass`, or `MySecondClass`, so I've written the method signature as

```
def foo(self, mytype: TDbBase) -> None:
```

But when I try to use the method and pass either an object of type `MyFirstClass` or an object of type `MySecondClass`, I get this error from `mypy`

```
Argument 1 to "foo" of "some_module.py" has incompatible type "MyFirstClass"; expected "TDbBase"
```

I've also tried writing the method signature like this, [after reading an example in PEP-484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects)

```
def foo(self, mytype: Type[TDbBase]) -> None:
```

But I get the same error,

```
error: Argument 1 to "foo" of "some_module.py" has incompatible type "MyFirstClass"; expected "Type[TDbBase]"
```

Comment: btw, why not just specifying the parent class as input type hint? Is it because there are other subclasses which are not accepted?

```python
def foo(self, mytype: MyBaseClass) -> None:
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with a TypeVar. mypy has many bugs unfortunately. BTW the difference between `TDbBase` and `Type[TDbBase]` is that `TDbBase` means "an instance of TDbBase (or of its subclass)" while `Type[TDbBase]` means "the class TDbBase (or subclass)"

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any error:

```
class MyBaseClass: ...
class MyFirstClass(MyBaseClass): ...
class MySecondClass(MyBaseClass): ...
TDbBase = TypeVar('TDbBase', bound=MyBaseClass)
def foo(mytype: TDbBase) -> None: ...
x = MyFirstClass()
foo(x)
y = MySecondClass()
foo(y)
```

See: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ded683650c84bd98e713522b61cb816c